# How to process passport authenticate function in as request handler function

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, middleware, passport-google-oauth2

I am creating a web application based on Node.js and Express 4. I am also using Passportjs and Google OAuth 2 Startegy for authentication.

I am trying to configure my routes in order to process requests. 
I have learned that this line work well:

```
router.get('/signin/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {failureRedirect: '/signin'}));
```

but when I decided to handle the route in the function, application stopped responding:

```
router.get('/signin/google/callback', function (req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('google', {failureRedirect: '/signin'});
});
```

Do I miss something? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback of the Google OAuth function should be something like this:

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

The `passport.authenticate()` is middleware with arguments `request,response, next`. You could also define your own middlewares or the last request handler.